# Listen to click event on overlapped sprites

Tags: actionscript-3, events, sprite

I have two sprites in my movieclip, one under the other, and i want both to listen to mouse clicks event.
I found that only the top level sprite receives the event when i click on it.
I need to dispatch the events on both, so I can't use mouseenabled=false.

Is there a simple workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the '`getObjectsUnderPoint`' method native to the DisplayObjectContainer

You can see how it works here:

http://snipplr.com/view/34945/as3-trace-movieclips-under-mouse/

and the AS3 reference here: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html

You would listen on the stage for any click event and if one occurs, check to see if the element you require is under that click position.

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of wrong examples of 'getObjectsUnderPoint'. It only returns SHAPES, I don't know wether it's a bug in AS3, or a wrong sentence in documentation. For the purpose of intercepting InteractiveObject instances it is totally useless.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% agree but you're not incorrect. I don't have flash anymore so it's hard to check but the method `getObjectsUnderPoint` is designed to return DisplayObjectInstance Or any DisplayObject. In the example provided on in the Adobe docs the instances are Sprites of which inherit DisplayObject.

Shapes in their own right are display objects as they also inherit DisplayObject therefore yes they will be in the methods `Array` return.

Comment: Hi, I thought that too. And according to documentation that's the way it should work. Alas, it only returns one display object, and afterwards only shapes. I know, it shouldn't be like this. I am not the only one experiencing this, it's apparently a known unfixed bug in AS3.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is, that you listen to the click-event on the upper sprite, and fire it again with

```
dispatchEvent(new MousEvent(event));
```

Have a look at the "bubble" property of the event.

Comment: +1. The only thing is you need to change it so it's 'new MouseEvent(event.type)'