# One button on top of onother

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I have two buttons one on top of another, the button that is in front is clickable. The button that is behind is not clickable. How can I make that button clickable too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listen to click event on overlapped sprites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924558/listen-to-click-event-on-overlapped-sprites)

Comment: This should be possible, but it sounds like the hit area of your front button is larger than it appears. Edit the button and check the "Hit" frame, to make sure it doesn't overlap the button behind.

Comment: Does you're foreground button have transparent areas that are supposed to click through to the bottom button?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to deliver a click event to anything that's below the foreground object that accepts mouse events, because it intercepts their dispatch. In order to manually provide a click event, you should listen for clicks on stage, then run `getObjectsUnderPoint()` and filter out those that you need to accept a click. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924558/listen-to-click-event-on-overlapped-sprites) is a question that has an example of how it should work.